# Find sum of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n \over (2n+1) 4^n}$$

I know the methodology of solving this kind of equations, though I'm having trouble preparing the expression for integrating. I have no idea what to do with -1 and how to go to 2n power.

Comment: My main issue with this problem was (-1)^n which is not explained in the proposed duplicate. So, I believe my question is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)4^n}=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1.
$$
This is obtained from the expansion of 
$$
\frac{1}{1+t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nt^{2n}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
$$
and hence
$$
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)4^n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)4^n}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\text{For}\;|x|<1\;:\;\;\frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}\implies\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Comment: Does the first equality originate from the sum of geometric series?

Comment: @JackNickolson Yes, of course: just substitute $\;x\to x^2\;$ in the series for $\;\frac1{1+x^2}\;$ (why can you do this?), when, of course, you assume that $\;|x^2|<1\iff |x|<1\;$